# animation an SVG <line> with its start/end points on a <path> elements

Tags: svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="jumpSequence" viewBox="200 -200 2900 1500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="keypointPaths">
        <path d="M2798 572 L2790 571 L2788 592 L2720 581 L2619 600 L2582 586 L2461 608 L2394 604 L2256 570 L2188 603 L2074 597 L2025 596 L1949 575 L1723 613 L1575 584 L1469 585 L1385 640 L1202 635 L1079 638 L1035 602 L931 444 L973 289 L841 239 L900 198 L883 193 L820 178 L811 203 L766 242 L696 324 L677 384 L668 464 L670 691 L597 785 L582 774 L496 653 L504 595 L549 563 L531 533 L472 543 L453 558 L468 541 " stroke="hsl(220, 100%, 50%)" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></path>
        <path d="M2696 594 L2682 595 L2654 600 L2614 596 L2527 608 L2472 602 L2370 613 L2290 602 L2161 614 L2102 618 L1971 609 L1931 585 L1822 612 L1718 612 L1603 585 L1517 580 L1413 667 L1239 629 L1186 630 L1096 611 L996 482 L1007 350 L944 213 L987 206 L971 165 L881 150 L818 187 L846 209 L777 292 L642 394 L585 493 L593 698 L512 826 L486 783 L401 676 L413 626 L430 597 L417 574 L366 594 L368 586 L367 564 " stroke="hsl(135, 100%, 50%)" stroke-width="2" fill="none"></path>
    </g>
    <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="hsl(200, 100%, 50%)"></line>
</svg>
```

I can't figure out how to animate the lines x1/y1 to be on the first path and x2/y2 on the second path.

- Both path elements do have the same number of points
- the line should arive at the keypoints at the same time, no matter the distance.
- a javascript aproach (updateing the line attributes) is not what I'm looking for.
- searching for e.g."svg animating line path" gave me just the drawing effect, not what I'm looking for.

with `<animateMotion>` and `<mpath>` it would be posible to animate a circle on the path but how do I use a path for start/end of a line?

Comment: I'm sory to hear that a javascript aproach is not what you are looking for because in JavaSvript you have the [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) method. This will return the point at a given distance along the path. You may use those points for the animation

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you want.  The only way would be to have a sparate `<animate>` for each of the four x1/y1/x2/y2 points and supply a long set of `values` numbers corresponding to points on the path.

Comment: Make the line longer, clip it using the paths and then animate it using animateTransform and one of the paths and it should be pretty close as the paths are fairly similar. It won't change angle though.